# Facing Errors "Deployment on AKS"

Tags: kubernetes, devops, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy a service to AKS which is dockerized and its image is in a container registry on Azure but I am facing these errors , I have used a service principal to provide necessary pull authentications.

kubectl logs -f new-service-deployment-6cc77c6b5-4mdxw
Error from server (BadRequest): container "new-service" in pod "new-service-deployment-6cc77c6b5-4mdxw" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
and this is my yml file for deployment;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: new-service-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: new-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: new-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: new-service
        image: debugdemoimage.azurecr.io/new-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Can some one please guide me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are facing an issue while trying to deploy a service to AKS which is dockerized and its image is in a container registry on Azure. The error message you are receiving indicates that the container is waiting to start and failing to pull the image. This could be due to authentication issues.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following solutions:

1. Make sure that the AcrPull role assignment is created for the AKS cluster's identity. You can check this by running the following command:

   ```
      az role assignment list --assignee <AKS-cluster-identity> --scope <ACR-resource-id> --role AcrPull
   ```
2. Check if the service principal that's associated with the AKS cluster is expired. To check the expiration date of your service principal, run the following commands:

   ```
      az account show
      az ad sp show --id <service-principal-id>
      az ad sp credential list --id <service-principal-id>
   ```

   If the secret is expired, update the credentials for the AKS cluster.
3. Make sure that the AcrPull role is assigned to the correct service principal. To check this, run the following command:

   ```
      az role assignment list --assignee <service-principal-id> --scope <ACR-resource-id> --role AcrPull
   ```

   If the container registry role assignment still refers to the old service principal, integrate the AKS cluster with the container registry again.
4. Make sure that the kubelet identity is referenced in the AKS VMSS. To find the kubelet identity of your AKS cluster, run the following command:

   ```
      az aks show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <AKS-cluster-name> --query "identity"
   ```

   Then, you can list the identities of the AKS VMSS by opening the VMSS from the node resource group and selecting Identity > User assigned in the Azure portal or by running the following command:

   ```
      az vmss identity show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --vmss-name <VMSS-name>
   ```

   If the kubelet identity of your AKS cluster isn't assigned to the AKS VMSS, assign it back.

In order to run your dockerized application on AKS (in this example I am using flask application), you can refer to below example.

Here I will be using a simple flask app that says  *This is a Hello World application*  using the below code. You can replace it with your own.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>This is a Hello World application</p>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Then containerize the app using docker. In this case, Flask application only requires the  `flask`  framework to run. Therefore, in the working directory, I will create a new file named ‘Dockerfile’ and use the following code:

```sql
FROM python:3.10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]
```

and then build it using  `docker build -t bravinwasike/flask-kubernetes .`

Output:  [image]

After creating the Docker image, ensure you push the Docker image into your Azure container repository using the following commands:

```xml
az login
az acr login --name <youracrname>
docker tag <the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR> <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_image_name_which_you_built>

docker push <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR>
```

[image]

next we will deploy the containerized Flask application to the created AKS cluster  [image]

Create a deployment yaml file that refers to the image that I just pushed in my acr  [image]

Deployment and service yaml file combined

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: bravinwasike/flask-kubernetes:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app-deployment
  ports:
  - port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

then apply the yaml

```xml
 kubectl apply -f <whatever_you_have_named_your_file>.yaml
```

[image]

Done.. Now when you do  `kubectl get pods`  your pods are up  [image]

Your flask app is up

[image]

References:

- [Fail to pull images from Azure Container Registry to Azure Kubernetes Service cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/cannot-pull-image-from-acr-to-aks-cluster)
- [AKS cluster identity and access management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-identity#use-managed-identities-for-aks)
- [Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77545013/kubernetes-pod-gives-image-pull-error-despite-docker-login-to-acr/77547245#77547245)